# Why does base.IsAuthorized always return false when creating a custom AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

This filter checks to make sure incoming arguments are good. It doesn't do security checks like checking session tokens.

I'd like to keep any existing security/authorization logic in place and just add my little bit to validate the input.

```
 public class ValidateMachineIdTokenAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var baseAuthorized = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext); // <-- always false
            CheckInput(actionContext); // throws exception if no good
            return true;
        }
       ...
   }
```

I could ignore `base.IsAuthorized` but like I said I want to keep whatever security is in place.

Comment: When using your attribute, does it have any roles or users set?  Is your user logged in?  With no users or roles specified in the attributes usage, the base attribute only looks to see if they're currently logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want authorization to be affected, you should use [ActionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) instead